# Add User Profile Picture to VisualForce Email Template

Tags: apex, visualforce-template

I have a running VisualForce Email Template for 'Case', and wish to include the Case.Owner profile picture.

I am reading ([here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/03/accessing-chatter-user-pics.html)) that one can use either `FullPhotoUrl` or `SmallPhotoUrl`, but this doesn't seem to be working for me - `<apex:image value="{$User.smallphotourl}"/>`.

Can you please assist?

Here is my current version of the VF Email Template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="[Internal] Case #{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}: {!relatedTo.Subject}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {font-family: arial; size: 12pt;}
            </style>
            <body>
                <br />• Case Owner: {!relatedTo.Owner.Name} <apex:image value="{$User.smallphotourl}"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>   
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PhotoUrl is not available with $User global variable. You need to query it in order to use with your template. So, you would need a controller along with the Visualforce template.

> Since, the photo is internal to Salesforce, you may not be able to
>   access the image as URL from external source directly. You would need
>   to convert you image to `base64` code and use it in your template.

**Custom Component (UserImg):**

```
<apex:component controller="TemplateController" access="global">
    <img src="{!currentUserImgURI}"/>
</apex:component>
```

**Template**:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="[Internal] Case #{!relatedTo.CaseNumber}: {!relatedTo.Subject}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <style type="text/css">
                body {font-family: arial; size: 12pt;}
            </style>
            <body>
                <br />• Case Owner: {!relatedTo.Owner.Name} <c:UserImg/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>   
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

**Controller**:

```
public class TemplateController {
    public String currentUserImgURI {public get; private set;}

    public TemplateController() {
        User currentUser = [SELECT SmallPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        currentUserImgURI = getDataUriFromUri(currentUser.SmallPhotoUrl);
    }

    public static String getDataUriFromUri(String url) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http binding = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = binding.send(req);
        Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
        return 'data:'+res.getHeader('Content-Type')+';base64,'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the Controller and altered the template as suggest, but am receiving the following error when trying to save the VF Email Template: Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.currentUserImgURI'

Comment: updated the answer...the get method for curren‌​tUserImgURI should be public...

Comment: thanks. I now receive 'Unsupported attribute controller in <messaging:emailTemplate>'. Shouldn't the Controller be a standalone component?

Comment: modified answer again...you need to use VF Component to use controller in a VF Email Template...

Comment: Thanks @SanTosh.   Can you perhaps assist with a test class for 'TemplateController' ?